# How to run or test my ionic app in android device which installed in vmware

Tags: android, visual-studio, ionic-framework, visual-studio-code, vmware

I use visual studio code in window 10.
I build app in ionic with visual studio code. 
I installed android device in VMware .
I want to run the app in android device (which I installed it in VMware) directly
without using android studio
Is there any solution ?
And is there a solution by using visual studio instead of visual studio code ?

I already installed android in VMware but I not sure about network setting bridge or NAT but I try both
but I couldn't run app in running android device which in VMware